# Implement classes in other classes via header

Tags: c++, class, header, game-development, raylib

I'm starting programming with raylib and tried to make a snake game. And I wanted to put everything that happens in a Game class. So i included the header file of my snake class and then tried to create an objekt in my game class but i am then getting the error : unknown override specifier.

```cpp
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "food.h"
#include "snake.h"

class Game {

public:
    void Draw();
    void Update();
    void MoveSnake();

private:
    Snake snake = Snake();      // error here
    Food food = Food();         // error here
};

#endif // GAME_H
```

The Problem is the same for both classes.
Exaple for class snake:

```cpp
#ifndef SNAKE_H
#define SNAKE_H

#include "header.h"

#define COLOR_R 43
#define COLOR_G 51
#define COLOR_B 24
#define COLOR_A 255

class Snake {

public:
    int i;
    void Draw();
    void Update();
    void Move();

private:
    std::deque<Vector2> body = { Vector2{6, 9}, Vector2{5, 9}, Vector2{4, 9} };
    Vector2 direction{ 1, 0 };
    int j;
};

#endif
```

I know that I dont get the error if i implement the class in the same file, but I want for future project and for good practise making it in a seperate file. Everything I found until now was nested classes but people are there just writing the class directly in another. Hope you can help me (Sorry for my bad english).

Rest of the files:

```cpp
#include "header.h"

Color green = Color{ 173, 204, 96, 255 };

double lastUpdateTime{};

bool eventTriggered(double interval) {
    double currentTime = GetTime();
    if (currentTime - lastUpdateTime >= interval) {
        lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    
    InitWindow(cellSize * cellCount, cellSize * cellCount, "Snake");
    SetTargetFPS(60);

    Game game = Game();

    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        BeginDrawing();

        if (eventTriggered(0.2)) {
            game.Update();
        }

        game.MoveSnake();
        
        // Drawing
        ClearBackground(green);
        game.Draw();

        EndDrawing();
    }

    CloseWindow();
    return 0;
}
```

Game cpp:

```cpp
#include "game.h"
#include "snake.h"


void Game::Draw(void) {
    this->snake.Draw();
    this->food.Draw();
}

void Game::Update(void) {
    this->snake.Update();
}

void Game::MoveSnake(void) {
    this->snake.Move();
}
```

snake cpp:

```cpp
#include "snake.h"

Snake::Snake() {};

void Snake::Draw(void) {
    for (size_t i{}; i < body.size(); ++i) {
        Rectangle segment = Rectangle{ this->body[i].x * cellSize, this->body[i].y * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize };
        DrawRectangleRounded(segment, 0.5f, 6, { COLOR_A, COLOR_G, COLOR_B, COLOR_A });
    }
}

void Snake::Update(void) {
    this->body.pop_back();
    this->body.push_front(Vector2Add(this->body[0], this->direction));
}

void Snake::Move(void) {
    if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_UP) && this->direction.y != 1) {
        this->direction = Vector2{ 0, -1 };
    }
    if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_DOWN) && this->direction.y != -1) {
        this->direction = Vector2{ 0, 1 };
    }
    if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_LEFT) && this->direction.x != 1) {
        this->direction = Vector2{ -1, 0 };
    }
    if (IsKeyPressed(KEY_RIGHT) && this->direction.x != -1) {
        this->direction = Vector2{ 1, 0 };
    }
}
```

the foot you can just take it out of the code its not neseccary
header:

```cpp
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <raylib.h>
#include <deque>
#include <raymath.h>

#include "game.h"

constexpr int cellSize{ 30 };
constexpr int cellCount{ 25 };

#endif
```

Comment: You have a circular reference: Snake.h needs header.h and header.h needs snake.h. Not sure if this is your problem yet, but only one of them can be the first one included. Looks like snake.h doesn't need header.h, so I'd remove header.h from snake.h

Comment: Looks like that's the problem. I can't reproduce your problem once I remove the cycle, but I got a different problem with the cycle, so your mileage may differ.

Comment: I could be on crack. Is `Game` defined in header.h or game.h? You could still have a cycle if header.h  sets up a cycle, but whatever's going in, I cannot reproduce your issue with what's been provided. If I can't reproduce, I can't give a tested answer. I recommend making a [mre] to make sure we have all of the necessary information in the question..

Comment: header.h doesnt have snake.h in it. in my header ther is iostream, raylib, deque and raymath and the game.h

Comment: Do us a favour and include header.h and then clearly label all of the files with their names. The clearer the question the more likely it is to be answered and to help future askers.

Comment: If you are able to reproduce this problem without raylib you'll be able to open the question up to answerers who don't have raylib installed. This is part of making a [mre]. Anything you don't need in order to reproduce the problem should be gone. Often once you've removed everything not essential there is so little left that you can't help but spot and fix the problem yourself.

Comment: I can try give me a minute

Comment: Side note: If a header doesn't need to include another header, don't include the header. You're adding complexity and slowing down the building of all of the files include the first header but don't need that's in the second header.  Header.h doesn't need any of the headers it includes, so it shouldn't include them.

Comment: well now i am doing the same thing but i dont get the error so i guess i have an error with my headers somewhere. But thanks for your help

Comment: Found the cycle: snake.h includes header.h which includes game.h which includes snake.h and uses `Snake`. Looking at it the way the compiler does we see this: https://godbolt.org/z/zPf8fzf1e note how `Snake` hasn't been defined when `Game` tries to use it. All snake.h cares about is `<deque>` and whatever header defines `Vector2` and should only include those two headers. It's tripping over unnecessary stuff.

Answer (score -1):

The issue could be that there is no Snake() function declared anywhere. You should create a constructor for each class, and declaring any instances of that type using the constructor.

Example:

```
class Snake

public:
    //constructor for the class
Snake()
{
    //code to be executed upon object creation
}
int i;
void Draw();
void Update();
void Move();
```

Then declaring an object of type Snake like this

```
Snake snake{};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried it like you said but im still getting the same error and the foot class even gut already an constructor.

Comment: Careful with "Could be" answers because an answer should be conclusive. Few things worse than guessing at an answer to an incomplete question, walking away for a while and coming back to find the question was clarified, your answer is dead wrong, and has been downvoted to hell and beyond.

Comment: If no constructor is defined the compiler will generate several, including `Snake()`.